# Warnings Command

Tags: discord, discord.py

Hello I need help with my warning command. I don't know how to make it say the stuff in chat, if you do show me how to fix this, I would preferably want this in an embed.

````html
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@has_permissions(manage_roles=True, ban_members=True)
async def warn(ctx,user:discord.User,*reason:str):
  if not reason:
    await ctx.send("Please provide a reason")
    return
  reason = ' '.join(reason)
  for current_user in report['users']:
    if current_user['name'] == user.name:
      current_user['reasons'].append(reason)
      break
  else:
    report['users'].append({
      'name':user.name,
      'reasons': [reason,]
    })
  with open('reports.json','w+') as f:
    json.dump(report,f)

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def warnings(ctx,user:discord.User):
  for current_user in report['users']:
    if user.name == current_user['name']:
      await ctx.send(f"```{user.name} has been reported {len(current_user['reasons'])} times : {','.join(current_user['reasons'])}```")
      break
  else:
    await ctx.send(f"```{user.name} has never been reported```")  

@warn.error
async def kick_error(error, ctx):
  if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
      text = "Sorry {}, you do not have permissions to do that!".format(ctx.message.author)
      await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, text)
````

Comment: You are taking a hard part by appending reason word by word. Just do this: `async def warn(ctx,user:discord.User,*, reason:str):` This would add everything after the user mention parameter as the reason parameter

Answer (score 0):

for and embed put in code. e.g:

```
embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{member}\'s Warning!',color=0x1d9521)
    embed.add_field(name='why he is warned',value=reason, inline=False)    
    embed.add_field(name="Moderator that warned", value={ctx.author.mention}, inline=False)
```

i am not sure if this would work but then to send it do

```
   await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

another way to send is

```
await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
```

to put this out of the embed you could do

```
await ctx.send("Why they are warned    `{reason}`/nThe Responsible Moderator   {ctx.author.mention}")
```

i am not sure if this would work but you can try